# Split line gives a null pointer exception in Processing 3

Tags: split, nullpointerexception, processing

I'm trying to split one string into two, but somehow it gives me an error ("null pointer exception"). The text file looks like this:

```
bat 32134
txt 12341
```

My code is as follows:

```
void txtToStrg(){  
  String[] lines = loadStrings("list.txt");
  for (int i = 0 ; i < lines.length; i++) {
  String[] splitLine = split(lines[i], ' ');
  print(lines[i]);
  fileTypes[i] = splitLine[0];
  fileSizes[i] = splitLine[1];
  println(fileTypes[i] + " = " + fileSizes[i]);
}
```

How can I fix this? Im using Processing 3.3.7.

Comment: Where is the file located relative to the sketch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is some `null` value in your array can you try adding the following code in your for loop

```
if(lines[i] != null) {
String[] splitLine = split(lines[i], ' ');
  print(lines[i]);
  fileTypes[i] = splitLine[0];
  fileSizes[i] = splitLine[1];
  println(fileTypes[i] + " = " + fileSizes[i]);
}
```

Comment: glad it solved, you can upvote the answer if it was useful :)

Comment: i wish i could but my reputation ist to low :(

Comment: oh wow im am an idiot i forgot to remove the comment and actually call the function when i tested it so this has not actually fixed it.

Comment: where did u define `fileTypes[i]`? I couldn't see it in the method

Comment: i initialised before the setup() like so: String[] fileTypes;

Comment: what about the size?

Comment: ohhh do i deed to specify it ? what if its an open ended array?

Comment: yeah ofcourse you need to, please specify the array size as the same size of length of array `splitLine`

Comment: what was the issue?

Comment: i did not determin the size of the array. i now set it to be as long as the lines array so: fileTypes = new String[lines.length];